# Drupal Services node filtering

Tags: 7, nodes, services

Is there a way to filter the nodes that come from a SERVICES node Endpoint, by a field or status?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`http://test/api/node?parameters[nid]=1&parameters[status]=1&fields=status,bid,title`

As always you can look at the tests.

Below you can see whats possible.

[image: Fetcher]

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer. It works for one of my scenario, but I have another requirement. I also have to filter based on a field in my Drupal which is a collection of list items. So how do I modify the query parameter such that the string which I am providing to filter should be contained as one of the listing item in the node? To be more clear, I want something in parameter like: "parameters[field_categories] contains 'fiction'". Here a book can be of more than one category, like a 'classic' as well as 'fiction' etc. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Well I simply tried something like: "parameters[field_categories]=fiction". This gives me a error: Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in /..../includes/common.inc on line 7359" Does this mean that it is indeed trying to fetch the 'fiction' category and failing somewhere while it is attempting to?

Comment: Ok I fixed the above mentioned problem by replacing var_export() call with serialize() call as mentioned [in one of the post](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/1631/var_dump-print_r-var_export/p1). Now I am getting this error "Invalid query provided, double check that the fields and parameters you defined are correct and exist. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_categories' in 'where clause'"  **Maybe this means that we cannot add query parameters for the custom fields created in Drupal? Is it?**

Answer (score 0):

At least when the resource is provided by Drupal Commerce Services, this appears to be slightly different. I had to go read the source, but the equivalent to the parameter query string parameter for commerce services is filter.