# Node filtering based on taxonomy terms

Tags: services

I followed [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7591/drupal-services-node-filtering) post, I am able to filter nodes based on content type and other parameters

```
http://test/api/node?parameters[nid]=1&parameters[status]=1
```

but I am not able to filter based on taxonomy terms (tid), problem is with nested json, how do I pass the parameter on URL for nested json?

I don't want to use services_views.

Below is my json data,

```
{
    "vid": "142",
    "uid": "2",
    "title": "Tomato",
    "log": "",
    "status": "1",
    "comment": "1",
    "promote": "1",
    "sticky": "0",
    "nid": "142",

..
..

 "field_category": {
        "und": [
            {
                "tid": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: can you able to pass taxonomy terms instead of tid?

Comment: no, this in created by default, I have no clue how to pass taxonomy terms. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I tried and it works perfectly,

```
http://test/api/node?parameters[nid]=1&parameters[field_category]=1
```